# Macbook pro showing "Starting Internet Recovery" instead of AHT

Tags: macbook-pro, apple-hardware-test

I try to make a long AHT test on my mid 2014 Macbook Pro. When I press D (same with alt-D) on boot it says :

```
Starting Internet Recovery
Restart           Shutdown
```

After a few seconds, it launches the basic AHT test.

But the Apple document says it should show an icon where I can launch the long AHT test.

Answer (score 3):

From [Apple's documentation on AHT](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1509):

> Some Macintosh computers that shipped with OS X Lion and later support
>   the use of Apple Hardware Test over the Internet. These computers will
>   start up to an Internet-based version of AHT if the hard drive does
>   not contain AHT.  An Internet-enabled connection via Ethernet or Wi-Fi
>   is required to use this feature. Internet-based AHT functions the same
>   as AHT on the hard drive or flash storage outlined above.

What you are using is AHT, it just doesn't have it pre-installed on your hard drive.

EDIT:
You should have the option to perform extended tests, it will be a checkbox you have the option of selecting before running the tests

EDIT 2:
As your mac was made after 2013, you are forced to use [Apple Diagnostics](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5781), which is why I assume you can't have access to the extended test options you see on the AHT documentation.

Comment: Hmm ok, it seems we can't perform long AHT on the new Mac products ?

Comment: According to the documentation it appears that way, unfortunately. Probably Apple trying to steer users away from self diagnostics so the genius bar looks busy!

Comment: And do you know an Apple software that can make real tests on RAM ?

Comment: I'm sure what you're using (Apple Diagnostics) would do 'real' tests on RAM. I can't speak first hand as I've never used the newer Apple Diagnostics.

Comment: Well, it does a 2 min test to check all the hardware. When just RAM needs hours to be tested.

Comment: If you're having RAM issues I'd just query Apple directly (Genius Bar appt.). And if there was a severe issue with RAM the mac wouldn't boot in the first place.

Comment: In this case, this is not a severe issue, just an issue. But the Diagnostic Mode says there may be an issue with a memory module. And memtest find a lot of issues. I just would test it more with an Apple tool, before going to the Genius bar (far from me). Anyway, thank you :)